# Compare 2 columns in excel using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, scripting

Hello I have an excel file (.xlsx) with 2 columns of data I want to compare the rows in column A with column B and output the value of column B in another generated excel file where the rows column A are  empty.

Any Help would be greatly appreciated

[Excel file showing data in column A and column B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X00dr.png)

Comment: And what have you tried yet? What didnt work? How would you compare the columns?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet should do the trick:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(io="file.xlsx", header=0)
df = df[df['A'].isna()]
df.to_excel("new_file.xlsx", columns=['B'], index=False)
```

Comment: Hello, I tried this. It returned the the rows of column B where there is a value in column A already. I needed it to return values of Column B where the rows in column A are empty.

Comment: @mike87 my bad, I have corrected the code to do the opposite.